# Safari extension and chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I have tried to port a Chrome extension that uses this API:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
afunction, 
{ urls: someblockedurls},
["blocking"]);
```

When a URL is blocked in the system, it won't be shown at all in the browsers, but with the extension instead a page defined in afunction will be shown, if the URL is in someblockedurls.

Is it possible to do the same in a Safari extension? Usually this API would be used to replace a URL with another, but it does never seem to be trigged if the URL is blocked, so anotherfunction is not called:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("beforeNavigate", anotherfunction, false);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, there was no solution. I haven't developed for Safari recently.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. I just added a 50 point bounty. Hopefully that helps.